# Backspace, left/right arrow in HSQLDB SqlTool commandline tool in UNIX

Tags: hsqldb

I'm trying to use sqlTool as an commandline oracle client in unix.
In interactive console when I try to delete something with backspace or try to move left/right on sql string strange characters are printed.

How can I solve this problem
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backspace has worked since the zeroth version of SqlTool because it uses standard Java tty I/O.  If backspace is not working, then your tty is not set up properly for Java, and possibly for non-Java programs.  Could be a locale variable or a stty setting needs to be changed.

As Fred noted, cursor keys are not supported because Java on UNIX does not support them.  However, Java on Windows does support cursor keys, including the up and down arrows for command history.

Answer (score 0):

Latest SqlTool allows using backspace, but cursor keys are not supported. This is explained in the guide here:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#sqltool_int-sect

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed for such commands with `rlwrap` in linux (I don't know in UNIX).
Simply install rlwrap and after start every console wrapping it with rlwrap:

Example :

```
rlwrap mysql .....
```

Now inside console has the arrow abilities.